# Неизменяемый масштаб сайта

Tags: css

Как в css задать так, чтобы при уменьшении страница html тоже уменьшалась?
То есть при заходе с мобильного устройства страница показывалась полностью.

Comment: Добавьте в head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать сайт рассчитанным под мобильные устройства, необходимо добавить соответствующий мета-тег "viewport" в блок `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Пример стандартной заготовки перед вёрсткой:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А... просто без соответствующего тэга meta <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: @MrRiseYTMrRise, если ответ помог, просьба пометить его решением. Скриншот галочки отметки: bit.ly/2Hss3VA